# Migrating app from Django 1.3.3 to 1.4?

Tags: django

I am trying to run ConceptNet (http://csc.media.mit.edu/docs/conceptnet/install.html) originally deployed on Django 1.3.
When running this app with Django1.4 on Mac OS X 10.6.8. (Snow Leopard) I get:

"ImproperlyConfigured: settings.DATABASES is improperly configured. Please supply the ENGINE value. Check settings documentation for more details."

To solve this I tried to create new config for 1.4 and run with SQLite database (ready to use) in my work directory.  I have changed the old contents of 'db_config.py'

```
DB_ENGINE = "sqlite3"
DB_NAME = "ConceptNet.db"
DB_HOST = ""
DB_PORT = ""
DB_USER = ""
DB_PASSWORD = ""
DB_SCHEMAS = ""
```

to new format for 1.4 in the same file ('db_config.py") :

```
DATABASES = {
   'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3', # Add 'postgresql_psycopg2', 'postgresql', 'mysql', 'sqlite3' or 'oracle'.
         'NAME': 'ConceptNet.db',                      # Or path to database file if using sqlite3. 
        'USER': '',                      # Not used with sqlite3.
        'PASSWORD': '',                  # Not used with sqlite3.
         'HOST': '',                      # Set to empty string for localhost. Not used with sqlite3.
          'PORT': '',                      # Set to empty string for default. Not used with sqlite3.
    }
}
```

This did not help.
I also renamed 'db_config.py' to 'settings.py' in the same working directory. I am still getting the same error.
What shall I do to make Django 1.4 find my configuration?

Thanks!
Dmitri

Answer (score 0):

In Django 1.4, the db_config.py is not required, you edit the settings.py file for the db info.

You just fill up the info inside the settings.py and then you syncdb it should work fine.

Comment: My app was developed for Django 1.3 and does not have settings.py. How and where can I create settings.py for 1.3 app? Where can I find syncdb?

Comment: when you create a project in Django 1.4, a setting.py will be created for you.

Comment: `./manage.py syncdb` for syncing the fields you created with the database

Comment: The problem is that ConceptNet was developed not by me but somebody else. It was developed for Django 1.3 and does not have settings.py and manage.py which Django 1.4 apps have. I am new to Django yet I think that Django 1.3 simply has no such settings.py and manage.py. So how to make it work in Django 1.4?

Comment: Well to be able to migrate your app from 1.3 to 1.4, may need other work to be done also as a lot of changes happened. Anyway you need to do some steps first. I think the best way to get started is to follow Django Tutorial and see how he created a project in https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/intro/